# Django is_authenticated and @login_required both not working

Tags: django, login-required

I tried to make some pages only visible when logged in.

I tried it with:

```
 def backend(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'web/backend-index.html')
    else:
        return redirect(reverse('web:login'))
```

and also with:

```
@login_required
   def backend(request):
   return render(request, 'web/backend-index.html')
```

The first code does not let me log in.

The second code does not let me log in but the url changes too: 
   http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/?next=/backend/

If I just render the view without checking if logged in, the login is working fine and I´ll be passed to the backend page.

The whole code is on github: https://github.com/psmaster1/BrainSystems/tree/master/smarthome/web

I don't get any error messages. It's just redirecting to the login page...

Comment: It is expected behavior to change to redirect the URL to `/login/`, etc. You can specify the view to which you want to redirect in the `@login_required`, but loging in is *not* performed in that view.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I already tried @login_required(login_url='/login/'), but it doesn't work eather. I know that it's not login automaticly. If i try to login after the redirect to the login-site it's just redirecting again to the login-site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your login form is incorrect - that's why you never actually authenticate. It was sending POST request to incorrect endpoint and it was not rendering actual form. This is how you can [render fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)

Change it to this:

```
<section class="login-form">
    <div class="login-fields">
        <h3>Login</h3>
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <div class="form-group">
                {{ login_form.username }}
                <label for="{{ login_form.username.id_for_label }}" class="control-label">Username</label><i class="bar"></i>
                {{ login_form.username.errors }}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{ login_form.password }}
                <label for="{{ login_form.password.id_for_label }}" class="control-label">Passwort</label><i class="bar"></i>
                {{ login_form.password.errors }}
            </div>

            <div class="button-container">
                <input type="submit" class="button" value="Login" />
            </div>
        </form>
        <p>Noch nicht Registriert?</p>
        <a href="{% url 'web:register' %}">Registrieren</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: OK. But then I'm losing all my style from the form. Is there no other way?

Comment: And if i try it without the authentification, the login works. I tested it like so: If user.is_authenticated: <p> logged in</p> (in the login.html file)

Comment: This. Maybe put `action=""` for good measure, but in any case `action="{% url 'web:backend' %}"` is not right. Login view has to post to itself (just as any other view).

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Already fixed it! The Problem was the action attribute in the form tag. It causes the troubles. Just removed it from the form tag and make a redirect in the login() method. Thanks guys! :)

Comment: That's what I said 15 minutes ago.

Comment: Yes i didn't see that you removed the action tag. Thank you! 
It is already late here so it took a bit longer :D

Comment: Yeah, I was expecting you to just copy-paste form, not deliberate fields. Should've been more detailed. Anyway, please accept answer according to [stackoverflow help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)